# List of Event Names Available on SDL Tridion

Tags: event-system, sites-9.6

We are using Tridion Sites 9.6 & Using Event Handler to Capture the Events triggered on CMS.

We are checking Event Name & Event Family as below

```
var eventname = tcmEventArgs.GetType().Name.Replace("EventArgs", "");
var eventfamily = tcmEventArgs.GetType().BaseType.Name.Replace("EventArgs", "");
```

if Schema Created, its logging as 
EventName : Save, EventFamily: Crud
EventName : DeleteApplicationData, EventFamily: ApplicationData, Item Type: Schema
EventName : CheckIn, EventFamily: Unlock
EventName : SaveApplicationData, EventFamily: ApplicationData

if Schema Deleted, its logging as 
EventName : Delete, EventFamily: Crud, Item Type: Schema, Event Phase: TransactionCommitted

What is "DeleteApplicationData" for Schema? if we restrict this Event Name, Structure Group Deletion events are not logging, means its showing same event name.

As per my requirement, we need to restrict Few unwanted Event Names from Log.
can you please provide Create/Delete/checkin/checkout/localize Event names for Folder,SG, Schema, component, Page,Categeory, ...etc

Answer (score 1):

I do not think such a list officially exists. The events are always following the naming convention of <Event><Object>, so you would have events for CreateFolder, DeleteFolder, CreateUser, SaveComponent, etc.

I don't think there's many better ways to do this than trial-and-error (which is why I disabled logging the load of a user profile [here](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/tridion-2011-reporting/blob/master/Tridion.Extensions.Reporting/EventSystem/TrackEverything.cs#L60) because this happens a lot of times during a user session).

Do you want to exclude event types (Delete, CheckOut, etc) or the combination of events for specific objects (Loading folders for instance)? If it's the combination of event+Object then it's obviously more complex.

Since you seem to have an embedded question in there, here's an embedded answer. ApplicationData is a type of object that can be attached to any IdentifiableObject, where you (and Tridion) can store any type of "Application Data" linked to that object. This could be literally anything, and if you delete a schema you are also deleting that schema's ApplicationData - hence why you see an event of type DeleteApplicationData.